# Running TestContainers on Jenkins inside Docker image

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, integration-testing, testcontainers

Recently, I've been trying to figure out how to run out integration tests using a TestContainers on Jenkins where they are ran inside another Docker image, but without any success.

TestContainers version: 1.13.0

Command that gets executed on Jenkins looks similar to this one (I've removed some env variables and private data):

```sh
docker run --rm -v /home/jenkins/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /home/jenkins/.sbt:/root/.sbt -v /home/jenkins/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2 -v /home/jenkins/workspace/re_FC-5370-create-dummy-endpoint@2:/home/jenkins/workspace/re_FC-5370-create-dummy-endpoint@2 -w /home/jenkins/workspace/re_FC-5370-create-dummy-endpoint@2 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock registry/build-java-app-image ./ci/test.sh
```

So, socket is exposed, `$PWD` is mounted and set as workspace as described here: https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/ but I'm still getting an error.

Now, there are two types of errors. First one is `NoRouteToHostException` which happens if in `test.sh` I simply run `./gradlew test` with this setup:

```java
@Container
private static PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12.2-alpine");

static class Initializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.datasource.url=" + postgresqlContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.datasource.username=" + postgresqlContainer.getUsername(),
                "spring.datasource.password=" + postgresqlContainer.getPassword(),
                "spring.datasource.driverClassName=" + postgresqlContainer.getDriverClassName()
        ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

*NOTE:* This works locally from terminal, simple run from IntelliJ and even from Docker image.

Second error happens if I try to setup a Docker networking in `test.sh` script:

```sh
docker network create --driver bridge "build-$HOSTNAME"
docker network connect "build-$HOSTNAME" $outerContainerId

export dockerNetworkId=$(docker network ls --no-trunc --filter name="build-$HOSTNAME" --format "{{.ID}}")
```

Setup that uses an exposed network ID:

```java
private static final String networkId = System.getenv("dockerNetworkId");

@Container
private static PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer)
        new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12.2-alpine")
                .withNetwork(Network.builder().id(networkId).build())
                .withNetworkAliases("test-database-container");

static class Initializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {     
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(
            "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://test-database-container:5432/test",
            "spring.datasource.username=" + postgresqlContainer.getUsername(),
            "spring.datasource.password=" + postgresqlContainer.getPassword(),
            "spring.datasource.driverClassName=" + postgresqlContainer.getDriverClassName()
        ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

So, I've created a network, linked it to a Jenkins container's network and exposed its ID so that I can fetch it in tests. In tests, I've created a container with that network ID and gave it a name so I can reference it in the URL.

This setup gives me `UnknownHostException` with message: `test-database-container` and I cannot figure out what's bothering it.

I've tried also some other variations where I'd setup a network, but use first approach or wouldn't setup a network and used second approach with Docker IP that TestContainers is returning instead of a network alias, but nothing worked. I always get one of those 2 exceptions.

Comment: Hi @Sven have you got it to work ?

Comment: Acutually, yes. Here's a fix with an explanation: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/2727

Comment: @SvenVidak the slack conversation as aged out unfortunately, could you share the explanation here?

Comment: @wave Full solution is documented in the PR linked in my comment above. This was what I did and it worked